# Is the GPU inside the CPU's pack in new CPUs

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, gpu

I've heard that GPU is inside the package of the CPU. That is, CPU has it near itself. Is it true?
If yes, what is the GPU with the graphics video card? Might we have two GPUs one with CPU and the other in the video card?

My next question: It's said the the GPU has much bigger speed in calculating/processing the instructions with less power consuming. Once again, if it's so, why don't manufactures produce only GPUs instead of CPUs?

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus

Comment: What you have heard is correct, many modern CPUs have a GPU built in to them as well, it is used in the case that the system does not have a dedicated graphics card. It is often preferred to use a dedicated graphics card because the one built into the CPU will not be particularly powerful and will use the same memory as the CPU rather than having its own dedicated memory.